# PHP Loop only brings out the last value from it in js

Tags: javascript, php

my value $viena_salis only brings out the last value(in this case united kingdom) when there are 6 other countries and all of them get the same "plan on visiting "united kingdom"?" I've tried moving var contentString to other places in the loop in hopes of the outcome changing but nothing seems to do it. This code places markers on a google map with numbers how many people have registered from each country, and should place different colored markers depending on the type of user roles(still working on the colored marker part).

`$indivitualios_salys` is an array of country names.

$google maps is an array of all world countries with coordinates.

I cant figure out what's wrong with it, in my eyes it should just loop js and echo the country name since `if($viena_salis==$gm_salis[0])` works with no problems.

if anyone has any ideas to what I did wrong, help would be much appreciated.

P.s I'm still new to php and js.

```
<?php $i=0;
        foreach ($indivitualios_salys as $viena_salis) {
            $i++;
            foreach ($Google_maps as $gm_salis) {
                if ($viena_salis==$gm_salis[0]) {
                    ?>
                    var contentString = '<div id="content" >'+
                            '<div id= "siteNotice">'+
                            '</div>'+
                              '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                              '<p>Plan on visisting "<?php echo $viena_salis; ?>"?</p>'+
                              '<p>Check out our <a href="https://biz4good.co/about/">welcome guide</a> </p>'+
                              '</div>'+
                              '</div>';
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString});

                    var <?php echo 'marker'.$i; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: {lat: <?= $gm_salis[1]; ?>, lng: <?= $gm_salis[2]; ?>},
                      map: map,
                      icon: <?php 

                foreach ($remeju_id as $con_id){
                  foreach ($country_user_id as $user_id_country) {
                    if($con_id==$user_id_country){
                      echo 'image_green_blue,';
                    }
                    if($con_id!=$user_id_country){ 
                      echo 'image_green,';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo 'image_blue,';
                    }
                  }
                }; ?>
                      label: { color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '14px', text: '<?php echo $elementCount[$viena_salis]; ?>' }
                    });
                    <?php echo 'marker'.$i; ?>.addListener('click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, <?php echo 'marker'.$i; ?>);
                    });
                    <?php
                }
            }
        };?>
      }
```

Edit: 
$indivitualios_salys- looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Aruba
    [1] => Lithuania
    [2] => Bolivia
    [3] => Ukraine
    [4] => Bosnia and Herzegovina
    [5] => Greece
    [9] => United Kingdom
)
```

$google_maps has all countries but in short it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Andorra
            [1] => 42.546245
            [2] => 1.601554
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => United Arab Emirates
            [1] => 23.424076
            [2] => 53.847818
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Afghanistan
            [1] => 33.93911
            [2] => 67.709953
        )
```

Comment: so you need contentString hold multiple values ?

Comment: @AmitSharma The code makes a clickable popup on markers that are placed on the map, since it shows "planning on visiting (country name here)" and those markers are on different countries it should change, so yeah.

Comment: @StackSlave Thank you for your tip and yeah, I understand that it's a mess and that there must have been ways to do it more efficiently, before I used django framework for college projects but once I entered internship(since it was the only option because there are no companies that work with python and accept internship students) I had do things with php, js, css, wp ect. So it's different from what I'm used to.

Comment: this holds all the values $viena_salis

Comment: Please provide examples of how your data in `$indivitualios_salys` and `$Google_maps` looks like. Also I'd really advise you not to mix PHP blocks within HTML or JS - it makes things unnecessarily hard to read.

Comment: @Fitzi I edited my post and pasted a bit of the data. Yeah it makes things really confusing after mixing things up, though at this time I don't know any better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i simplified your code and prepared a short snippet of code , in my code  **$viena_salis** is iterating all matched values of array , you can just check it out by copy below code and see in console it will result you

Andorra

Afghanistan

```
$indivitualios_salys = array('Andorra','Lithuania','Afghanistan','Ukraine','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Greece','United Kingdom');


$Google_maps = array(
                array('Andorra',42.546245,1.601554),
                array('United Arab Emirates',42.546245,1.601554),
                array('Afghanistan',42.546245,1.601554),

            );


        $i=0;
        foreach ($indivitualios_salys as $viena_salis) {
            $i++;
            foreach ($Google_maps as $gm_salis) {
                if ($viena_salis==$gm_salis[0]) {
                    ?>
                    <script>
                        var viena_salis = '<?php echo $viena_salis ?>';
                        console.log(viena_salis);
                    </script>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        };

?>
```

Above code is tested and worked,

i gave you above solution as answer of your statement , 
" **my value $viena_salis only brings out the last value(in this case united kingdom)** ",